# Why iframing yahoo.com can have no scrollbar whatsoever, but iframing google.com will have scrollbar?

Tags: html, css, iframe, scrollbar

the code is

```
<iframe scrolling="no" src="http://www.google.com" width="200" height="100"></iframe>hello
```

there is no way to get rid of the scrollbar?  (should work in all IE 7, 8, FF, Chrome, Safari)

If it iframes yahoo.com, then it works...

sample:
http://jsfiddle.net/tEXmL/1/
http://jsfiddle.net/tEXmL/2/

Comment: What browser? I don't see a scrollbar in both samples in FF 3.6.12.

Comment: that's weird... at least in Chrome, it is doing that

Answer (score 1):

Could be because Google explicitly sets `overflow-y: scroll` in their CSS whereas Yahoo does not.

Answer (score 0):

You can use seamless attribute of iframe.